# Sending a custom pyqtsignal from one main window to another

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-signals

beginner python coder here. I created two main windows in qt designer. In the first window i have got a combobox(cb) with three items and a push button(Button1), and in the other window i have got a LineEdit(edit). When i push the button in the first window i want to display the text (of the current item chosen in the combo box) in the LineEdit which i have created in the second main window.

I followed several examples online but i cant seem to find something that works for me. All of the examples are done by building the windows in code (as opposed to Qt Designer). People who design their windows on Qt designer seem to share the same problem as i do.

I would really appreciate if someone can show me how to send the signal with windows designed in Qt designer. This would really solve a big bottle neck i have currently got and i can implement the same strategy in other areas of my code.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class First_Window(QMainWindow):

    got_signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(First_Window,self).__init__()
        loadUi('first_window.ui',self)
        self.setWindowTitle('First Window')
        self.Button1.clicked.connect(self.On_buttonclick_clicked)

    def On_buttonclick_clicked(self):
        self.got_signal.emit(self.cb.currentText())

class Second_Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Second_Window, self).__init__()
        loadUi('second_window.ui', self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Second Window')
        self.dcc = First_Window()
        self.dcc.got_signal.connect(self.show_it)

    def show_it(self, the_signal):
        self.edit.setText(the_signal)
        print(the_signal)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    fw = First_Window()
    fw.show()
    sw = Second_Window()
    sw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code is a simplified version of the code i am working on but they share the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation:

The main problem is that you have created 2 First_Window:

- One you use to show, and
- The other one where you make the connection between the got_signal and show_it.

#### Solution:

Just create a First_Window that is displayed and make the connection:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class First_Window(QMainWindow):

    got_signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(First_Window, self).__init__()
        loadUi("first_window.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle("First Window")
        self.Button1.clicked.connect(self.On_buttonclick_clicked)

    def On_buttonclick_clicked(self):
        self.got_signal.emit(self.cb.currentText())


class Second_Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Second_Window, self).__init__()
        loadUi("second_window.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Second Window")

    def show_it(self, the_signal):
        self.edit.setText(the_signal)
        print(the_signal)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    fw = First_Window()
    fw.show()
    sw = Second_Window()
    sw.show()

    fw.got_signal.connect(sw.show_it)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Fabulous! works like a charm! My logic wast there yet but i applied the same strategy in my code at it is looking good! Thanks alot!